# Qt: Increase resolution of map

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt5.12

I have a [map](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-map.html) whose `visibleRegion` I set to a given `georectangle`, but the resulting render has a terrible resolution. As I understand it, the map loads the tiles from a lower `zoomLevel` and scales it up to fit the `visibleRegion`, instead of loading tiles from a higher `zoomLevel` and scaling it down. Is there a way of changing this behavior?

The plugin I use is

```
Plugin { name: "osm" }
```

[image: Map with terrible resolution]

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't have internet connection; therefore, qt fails to download the area. So, what you are looking for is probably an [offline map](https://www.qt.io/blog/2017/05/24/qtlocation-using-offline-map-tiles-openstreetmap-plugin). The link has an example project, it basically uses this plugin.

```
plugin: Plugin {
    name: 'osm'
    PluginParameter {
        name: 'osm.mapping.offline.directory'
        value: "path/to/your/directory"
    }
}
```

What you needed to do is downloading the tiles beforehand and giving their directory path to the `value` parameter.